# Rails 3.1 and auto detection of RSS

Tags: xml, macos, safari, rss, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Good day!

I try to implement auto detection of rss via browsers in my web application. I know about auto_discovery_link_tag and i tried to use it. I test it by Safari. But here is problem - When i try:

**/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<%= auto_discovery_link_tag( :rss, {:controller => "users_controller", :action => "show"} ) %>
```

Rails's server shows

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"users_controller", :action=>"show"}
```

When i just try

**/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<%= auto_discovery_link_tag( :rss ) %>
```

Browser shows that RSS is available on each page (which is wrong) and doesn't show it.

Here is my code:

**/app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user  = User.find( params[:id] )
    @title = @user.name                                                       
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(:page => params[:page])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.rss { render :layout => false }
    end
  end
```

**/app/views/users/show.rss.builder**

```
xml.instruct! :xml, :version => "1.0" 
xml.rss :version => "2.0" do
  xml.channel do
    xml.title "Feed of #{@user.name}"
    xml.description "Rails. Feed of user."

    for post in @microposts
      xml.item do
        xml.title post.id
        xml.description post.content
        xml.pubDate post.created_at.to_s(:rfc822)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `_controller` part isn't necessary, rails appends it automatically:

```
<%= auto_discovery_link_tag( :rss, {:controller => "users", :action => "show"} ) %>
```